# В таблицу IDT вместо указателя вписывается часть кода. Где ошибка?

Tags: c++, прерывания

Использую VirtualBox для тестов. Тестовая конфигурация [виртуальной машины](https://github.com/adokenai/nose/blob/master/tst.ova)
После компиляции и запуска, в таблицу IDT пишутся первые 8 байт кода обработчика, а не адрес обработчика. Если и обработчик и настраивающая функции находятся  в одном файле, то всё в порядке. 
Дополнительное тестирование показало, что компилятор вместо команды lea использует команду mov. Обычно это нормальное поведение, но в данном случае в таблицу попадает не адрес, а код. Почему - не понятно.

Для проверки данной ситуации создал отдельно файлы
Test1.c (главный):

```
 typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) _idt_descriptor
{
    unsigned short wLow; //16bits
    unsigned short wSelector; //16bits
    unsigned cIST:3; 
    unsigned :5; //8bits
    unsigned type:5;
    unsigned dpl:2;
    unsigned present:1;//8bits
    unsigned short wLHigh; //16bits
    unsigned int uHHigh; //32bits
    unsigned int uReserved; //32bits
}IDT_DESCRIPTOR __attribute__((aligned(16))); //128bits
typedef struct _interrupt_frame{
  unsigned long ulIP;
  unsigned long ulCS; //lcall
  unsigned long ulFlags; //int
  unsigned long ulSP; //int, CPL!=RPL
  unsigned long ulSS; //int, CPL!=RPL
}IFRAME;
```

Определения препроцессора для сокращения записей

```
#define INTERRUPT __attribute__((__interrupt__, aligned(8))) void

#define voidINT(name) __attribute__((__interrupt__, aligned(8))) void name (IFRAME*)

typedef INTERRUPT (*INTSR)(IFRAME*);
```

Собственно таблица IDT и функция, заполняющая поля.

```
static IDT_DESCRIPTOR __attribute__((aligned(4096))) IDT[256];
void SetIDTDescriptor( unsigned char vector, void* offset, unsigned short wSelector, unsigned char type=0xE, unsigned char ist=0){
    IDT[vector].uHHigh=((unsigned long)offset >> 32);
    IDT[vector].wLHigh=((unsigned long)offset >> 16);
    IDT[vector].wLow=((unsigned long)offset & 0xFFFF);
    IDT[vector].wSelector=wSelector;
    IDT[vector].type=type;
    IDT[vector].present=1;
    IDT[vector].cIST=ist;
}
void RegisterInt(unsigned char cInt, INTSR hHandler, bool isTrap=false){
  unsigned short wCodeSegment;
  asm("mov %%cs,%0":"=r"(wCodeSegment));
  SetIDTDescriptor(cInt, (void*)hHandler, wCodeSegment, 0xE | isTrap);
}


extern voidINT(int_UI);
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) _idtr {
    unsigned short wSeg;
    void *hOffset;
}IDTR __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

Главная функция. Для загрузки используется UEFI.

```
void efi_main(void*, void*){
  asm("cli");
  asm("lidt %0"::"m"(IDTR{ sizeof(IDT)-1, IDT}));

  RegisterInt(0x00, int_UI);
  for(;;);
}
```

Test2.c (собственно сам обработчик. В данном случае - пустышка так как сам обработчик не вызывается из-за неверной записи в таблицу IDT):

```
typedef struct _interrupt_frame{
  unsigned long ulIP;
  unsigned long ulCS; //lcall
  unsigned long ulFlags; //int
  unsigned long ulSP; //int, CPL!=RPL
  unsigned long ulSS; //int, CPL!=RPL
}IFRAME;
__attribute__((__interrupt__)) __attribute__((aligned(8))) void int_UI (IFRAME* frame){
  volatile unsigned int a, b, c, d, e, f; //dummy code
  a=(unsigned int)(unsigned long)(frame);
  b=(unsigned int)((unsigned long)(frame)>>32ul);
  c=(a>>7);
  d=c+(b>>5);
  e=d+(a>>2);
  f=d>>16;
  (void)e;
  (void)f;
  for(;;);
}
```

И Makefile для сборки. Использовался оригинальный, поэтому могут быть лишние команды не влияющие на сборку. Папки build и debug должны уже существовать:

```
GCC=@g++ -O3 -m64 -c -DDEBUG -I$(PWD)/include\
    -mabi=ms -mno-red-zone -mno-80387 -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mgeneral-regs-only \
    -nostartfiles -nostdlib  -nostdinc  -nostdinc++ -undef \
    -finline-functions -falign-functions=16 -falign-labels=1 -falign-loops=1 -falign-jumps=1 \
    -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fpermissive -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions \
    -fno-stack-protector -fshort-wchar -free -fno-toplevel-reorder -fsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields \
    -Wno-write-strings -Wno-multichar -Wfloat-equal -Wextra -Wpadded -Wunused -Wunused-function \
    -Wuninitialized -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value

LD=@ld
OBJ=$(PWD)/build
DBG=$(PWD)/debug
INCLUDE=$(PWD)/include
MF=-e OBJ="$(OBJ)" DBG="$(DBG)" INCLUDE="$(INCLUDE)" GCC="$(GCC)" LD="$(LD)" 

SUBDIRS=$(shell ls -p | grep .*\\/ | sed -e 's/\/$$//')

ONAME:=$(PWD)/$(shell basename $(shell pwd))
objects = $(subst .c,.o,$(shell ls *.c))

all: $(PWD)/nosex64.efi

$(PWD)/nosex64.efi: subdirs $(objects)
    $(LD) -x -nostdlib --entry `readelf -W -s $(PWD)/build/test1.o | grep -i -o "[^ ]*efi_main[^ ]*"` -d $(OBJ)/*.o --oformat pei-x86-64 -mi386pep --subsystem 10 -o $@
    @cp $@ $@.dbg
    @objdump -d $@.dbg >$@.dsf
    @strip --strip-unneeded  -K start -R .idata -R .eh_fram -R .note -R .comment -R .note.gnu.gold-version $@

%.o: %.c
    $(GCC) -S -I $(INCLUDE) $< -o $(DBG)/$@.S
    $(GCC) -I $(INCLUDE) $< -o $(OBJ)/$@

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    @make $(MF) -C $@ 

.PHONY: install
INST_DIR=/media/nose/efi/boot/ #Это путь к образу тестовой машины. Можно просто вручную кидать nosex64.efi
install: nosex64.efi
    @-rm -f $(INST_DIR)$<
    @cp $< $(INST_DIR)
    @sync
    @sleep 1
    @cmp -s $< $(INST_DIR)$< && echo "Done" || echo "Failed"
```

Удаление параметра permissive и указание конкретного значения для сегмента кода проблему не устраняет.

Comment: Странно, что для сборки С кода используется компилятор C++, да еще с аргументом `-fpermissive`. Также странно видеть вставки из инлайн ассемблера.

Comment: Это чтобы не менять параметры при использовании классов. Это уже третий вариант кода, и в предыдущем использовались классы. Вставка нужна для получения действительного номера кодового сегмента. Можно это значение явно задать и удалить permissive. Проблема останется. Только что проверил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сделать "ход конём": создать переменную, ссылающуюся на обработчик прерываний и уже её использовать для записи в IDT.

Более правильное решение: указать параметр -fno-pie для компилятора.