# Что нужно сделать, чтобы при компиляции под x64_32 передать ссылку на функцию?

Tags: c++

```
void main_loop(const CMsg); //прототип функции
typedef void (*HPROC)(const CMsg); //тип-функция
bool MessageSubscribe(HPROC hCallback, uint32_t uEvent); //прототип функции, в которую нужно передать указатель функции.
```

При вызове MessageSubscribe в hCallback передаётся часть кода функции main_loop, а не указатель. Изменение HPROC на void* ничего не меняет. 
Использование амперсанда (&main_loop) вообще ни на что не влияет. 
Проблема возникает если main_loop в отдельном файле.

"Ход конём", описанный в [В таблицу IDT вместо указателя вписывается часть кода. Где ошибка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826761/%d0%92-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-idt-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0/827073#827073) применять нельзя.

Работу проверяю в VirtualBox со включенной отладкой. И в вызов call попадает не адрес функции, а начало кода функции.

Внутренний вывод, что в переменной подтверждает. Специально ввёл отладочные строки (kprint - это аналог printf без поддержки форматирования, второй параметр - перевод строки):

```
  kprint((HANDLE)*main_loop, true);
  kprint((HANDLE)main_loop, true);
  kprint((HANDLE)&main_loop, true);
  MessageSubscribe(&main_loop, EV_SYS);
  MessageSubscribe(&main_loop, EV_KBD);
```

Нормальные адреса кода в пределах 0x400000 ... 0x4FFFFF

[image: Вывод команды kpint]

Вывод as: [kmain.o.S](https://yadi.sk/i/pPmpzx2U3WfFe2) и [main_loop.o.S](https://yadi.sk/i/zO5f3x4l3WfFeN)

Comment: "в hCallback передаётся часть кода функции main_loop, а не указатель." а как вы это определили? Можете написать подробнее.

Comment: "И в вызов call попадает не адрес функции, а начало кода функции." Не могли бы вы привести текст отладки, скриншоты, чтобы было понятно что имено отображает отладчик.

Comment: *"При вызове MessageSubscribe в hCallback передаётся часть кода функции main_loop, а не указатель."* - с чего вы это взяли?

Comment: VTT, всё в описании есть.

Comment: А функция main_loop вообще большая? Просто она же вся может не поместится в указатель.

Comment: Unick, это шутка? В любом случае больше 8 байт. И она не определена в заголовочном файле, чтобы быть inline.

Comment: В описании у вас этого нет. `*main_loop` `main_loop` и `&main_loop` ожидаемо выдают одинаковый результат.

Comment: VTT, начиная со слов "Внутренний вывод, что в переменной..."

Comment: А есть возможность сгенерить asm файл, чтобы посмотреть что происходит на низком уровне?

Comment: Ну вот вы напечатали три раза один и тот же указатель, но с чего вы взяли, что *"в hCallback передаётся часть кода функции main_loop, а не указатель"*  - не ясно… У вас вылезает какая-то ошибка при вызове функции по переданному указателю?

Comment: Unick, добавил ссылки на соответствующие файлы.

Comment: @VTT я так понимаю доказательством является это утверждение "Нормальные адреса кода в пределах 0x400000 ... 0x4FFFFF"

Comment: @VTT вылезает. General Protection.

Comment: А как тогда код `main_loop` (в другом файле) выглядит? Вообще тут стоит привести [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Во всяком случае, что-то более полное.

Comment: @VTT, в описании есть ссылка на аналогичный вопрос. Проблема абсолютно идентичная. Метод решения в общем случае неприемлем.

Comment: Т.е. это тоже efi исполняемый файл с хитрой сборкой, ассемблерными вставками и кучей специфичных расширений? В том виде, в каком оно представлено здесь, проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: @VTT, функция и вызывающий код должны быть в разных файлах. В одном файле всё работает прекрасно. Это указано в последнем предложении первого абзаца. Про расширения вообще не понял. Самый чистый код, без библиотек, специфических команд процессора и т.п. Ассемблерные вставки только там, где их не избежать.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что если это собрать как обычное С приложение, допустим `gcc -o "test.exe" "file1.c" "file2.c"`, то все должно работать нормально.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78137/discussion-between---and-vtt).

Comment: Отключить или снизить оптимизацию компилятора? -O0 например. Так же можно попробовать описать функцию с флагом extern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию, при компиляции 64-битного кода (AMD64/EM64T) включен параметр PIE, то есть данные берутся относительно командного регистра RIP.

Когда происходит вызов функции, подставляется её адрес, а при передаче как данные, используется относительный указатель на данные, а не на функцию, поскольку данные не должны вызываться как функция.

Решение: указать параметр -fno-pie для компилятора.